# I broke this JS when I added arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code worked when every variable was single. When I put everything in arrays, it didn't work. It is two drop down list with numbers. Each number from each list will eventually display another number based on the two numbers (which I'm not sure how to do that either).

Almost everything I find on arrays is using it with the for statement.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="pwh.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:15px;
width:297px;
height:59px;
z-index:1;
color:000;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="apDiv1">
<p>
<select name="marked" id="marked" onchange="checkdata(this); ">
<option value="">SELECT</option>
<option>201</option>
<option>206</option>
<option>224</option>
<option>319</option>
</select>
<select name="marked1" id="marked1" onchange="checkdata(this); ">
<option>SELECT</option>
<option>201</option>
<option>206</option>
<option>224</option>
<option>319</option>
</select>
<button onClick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(){
var select1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("marked").value);
var select2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("marked1").value);
if (select1 == a && select2 == b)
 {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "it works";
}}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js file:

```
var a=["201","206","224"];
var b=["319","333","354","355","c355"];
var c=["356","a356","357","a357","413","443","a444"];
var d=["511","512","513","514","535"];
var e=["7004","7005","7039","710","712"];
var f=["6009","6010","6070"];
var g=["6005","6051","6063","6101","6151","6201","6351","6951"];
var h=["5456"];
var i=["5454"];
var j=["5154","5254"];
var k=["5086"];
var l=["5083"];
var m=["5052","5652"];
var n=["5005","5050"];
var o=["3004","Alc-3004"];
var p=["2219"];
var q=["2014","2036"];
var r=["1100","3003","Alc-3003"];
var s=["1060","1070","1080","1350"];
```

Then I will have more variables with the other numbers to be displayed based on the numbers chosen. Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is the method `checkdata()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing a number to an array is not useful. If you need to check if an array contains some value, you can do something like this:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("marked").value;
var select2 = document.getElementById("marked1").value;
if (a.indexOf(select1) > -1 && b.indexOf(select2) > -1) {...}
```

Dropped the `parseInt()`s since you've strings in arrays.

[`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) at MDN. Notice, that this method is not supported in IE<9.

---

**EDIT**

If you're implementing datastructure like this [Aluminum filler
metal selection chart](http://www.esab.co.uk/gb/en/support/upload/XA00125520-aluminium-welding-quality-and-knowledge-may-2011-2.pdf), I'd prefer slightly different approach.

- Put the alloys grouped on row headers to `option`s of a `select` as they appear.
- For the second `select`, reverse the first-one.
- Create a `data` object, which has two properties: `quality` [3D Array]
  and `filler` [2D Array].

  - `quality[]` represents rows in chart and `quality[][]` columns.
  - Each `quality[][]` is an array containing all "Quality Alternatives" for the two selected base alloys.
- `filler[]` represents rows, each containing an array of suitable filler materials.

Here's an image of the data structure. (`base1[0] === base2[C] - base1[R] === base2[0]`.)

[image: Data structure]

Please check [a live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMCUL/) to see, how the data should be constructed. (`data` in the fiddle has been populated with values from the last six rows of the ESAB's chart linked above.)

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks. But say, if instead, select2 = a and select1=b. It doesn't matter what order the letters come out, as long as I get two letters. How could I accomplish that.

Comment: This is a form for aluminum tig welding. You input the two metals you are welding together and then it will tell you what filler rod you need to weld it with. To give you a better idea of what I am doing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @peedeefish I'm not sure what you mean with "`getting letters`", array names perhaps? Are you basicly trying to create a data structure [like this (pages 6 - 7)](http://www.esab.co.uk/gb/en/support/upload/XA00125520-aluminium-welding-quality-and-knowledge-may-2011-2.pdf)?

Comment: Yes exactly, although not the same chart. You put in your base metals (top row and left column) and it will tell you the right filler rod to use.

Comment: Wow. that is awesome. You either did some research or you are a welder, not sure, but thank you so much.

Comment: @peedeefish Actually I'm engineer, welding parameters belong to my daily job : ).